# automatic deployment using shell script in windows

Tags: bash, deployment, automation, google-cloud-platform

I wrote a code using google cloud functions and google dataflow that reads from csv and then inserts into BQ

I used config files to automate.
Now i want to create a shell script that automatically creates the dataflow template(using mvn) and deploys the cloud function.

However, when I am running the shell script, the template is successfully created but the cloud function is not deployed as it states:
google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: line 129: exec: python: not found

I need  a resolution for including the gcloud into my bash shell script.

Comment: And - do you have python in your PATH?

Comment: I agree with the previous user.  Check your PATH.  If you want, find where the python executable lies and use the full path to it in your script (i.e. instead of `python`, do `/usr/bin/python` or wherever it is located).

Comment: @user1934428  isnt python automatically installed when we install google-cloud-sdk?my cloud function is in nodejs and the dataflow is in java.

Comment: @user3746835 : It must be installed **and** in your PATH. I would not rely on it and instead verify this first.